# Can't resolve DNS over VPN except from nslookup

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn, dns

I've set up a VPN connection between two of my computers for DNS resolution. However, only `nslookup` can actually resolve any names. Both `ping` and browsing fail. How can I get the names to resolve no matter what software is trying to resolve them?

#### `ipconfig /all`:

```
C:\Users\CJDennis>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : portable
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **-**-**-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **-**-**-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

PPP adapter VPN Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VPN Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.42.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.42.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi M.2 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **-**-**-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::98b1:5432:e500:da38%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.18(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, 17 March 2018 10:48:43 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, 17 March 2018 1:48:11 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 81288674
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-1A-6D-D6-30-8D-99-F4-1B-74
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 198.142.152.164
                                       198.142.152.165
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **-**-**-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

The client's IP is `10.0.42.7` and the host's IP is `10.0.42.1`. The client is a Windows 10 machine.

#### `nslookup` and `ping` commands:

```
C:\Users\CJDennis>nslookup learn
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.42.1

Name:    learn
Address:  10.0.42.1


C:\Users\CJDennis>ping learn
Ping request could not find host learn. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I have. Are any connections other than the VPN significant considering that `nslookup` is using it?

Comment: Yes. Windows' decision on how to perform name resolution is based on the whole picture of your network configuration.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Done.

Comment: Do you want **all** DNS requests to go to the server on the other side of the VPN connection? Or only certain lookups?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I don't mind as long as my locally defined names always get resolved. It should be possible to forward non-local name requests to an internet DNS. For all other traffic I'd prefer only local names to use the VPN and all others to use the base network connection to reduce double data usage.

Comment: I believe your solution is to edit your VPN adapter's configuration and clear the **Use default gateway on remote network** box. Do this for IPv4 and v6. I'll post as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator That didn't work, but by using Wireshark, I can see that `nslookup` is using DNS on port 53, but `ping` is using NBNS (NetBIOS) on port 137. If I disable NetBIOS for the VPN, it falls back to the base connection. `ping` uses NetBIOS on the base connection whether it's enabled on the VPN or not.